# My array curve doesn't follow curve

Tags: modifiers

I applied scale, origins of all object are at the world origin, and you see where the first and last vertices are, and where the first and last chain is. I want my first and last vertice to be right next to first and last chain so I can bend it. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need put the chain's origin at the same point as the curve's origin, which is not the case currently (you don't need to put all the origins at the world centre, which was not the case anyway).

Also, as you've used an empty as object offset in the *Array* modifier, you also need to move it along the chain object, otherwise it will mess the *Array*. So:

- Select the curve, press right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*
- Select the chain object, shift select the empty, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*

It should work.

Also make sure that the curve's direction is good. FIrst enable their visibility in the *Viewport Overlays*. To switch their direction, right click > *Switch Direction*.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer! I checked that but it didn't help exactly, but probably I didn't explained my problem well. You see on my picture this one vertice(close to origin cursor) is the starting vertice of chain, but start of the chain is far behind and because of that I can't control that part of chain path. I hope now my problem is clearer.

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I uploaded.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=l51rEy5R" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/l51rEy5R/)

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer, I hope it's ok

Comment: That's it. I'm not sure how I managed to mess everything, but thanks for help. Now it is working as I wanted!